Is there a way to run unit tests on .net fiddle?
I'd love to use dotnet fiddle (https://dotnetfiddle.net/) to demo some behavior via unit tests
Fiddle usually builds as a console app, invoked with Program.Main
But tests usually run in a class library, invoked with dotnet test
Is there anyway to get tests to work in fiddle?
Example fiddle (where tests don't work)
Example Test
public class CalculatorTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void Add_WhenCalledWithTwoIntegers_ReturnsTheirSum()
    {
        // Arrange
        var calculator = new Calculator();
        
        // Act
        var result = calculator.Add(2, 3);

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(5, result);
    }

    private class Calculator
    {
        public int Add(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
}

Note: The code parts of this question might also be relevant on StackOverflow, but I specifically want to get this working within the context of dotnetfiddle.  The code will run just fine locally

unit test run very differently than normal code. as such if the fiddle does not support such a feature, you won't be able to make it work as a traditional unit test run. you can always create some kind of runner file to execute your tests in order, and rewrite your test methods to run as standard functions, but they will cease to be unit tests as .net understands them.

As already mentioned in the comments by Frank Thomas, it is not possible to run unit tests in .Net Fiddle the same way you do locally.
As he also mentions you can create your own runner to execute the tests as part of the console application that .Net Fiddle provides.
However, you don't have to create these runners from scratch: both NUnit and XUnit provide ways to do this (rather) easily.
I tried out both frameworks and unfortunately only NUnit worked in .Net Fiddle (seems like they use a way to run the project where reflection doesn't work properly).
The XUnit approach did work in jdoodle (and maybe does in other online editors, I just stopped trying after I found one that worked).
So you will need to decide on a compromise: either switch to NUnit and stick to .Net Fiddle or stick to XUnit and switch to a different online editor...
NUnitLite Runner
Demo in Dotnet Fiddle
The following snipped should work on .Net Fiddle using the NUnitLite package.
(Thanks to my colleague Markus for showing me this)

// configure the editor to reference the following packages:
// * NUnit
// * NUnitLite

// Shortcut for .Net Fiddle:
// @nuget: NUnit
// @nuget: NUnitLite

using NUnit.Framework;
using Assert = NUnit.Framework.Legacy.ClassicAssert;

public class CalculatorTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Add_WhenCalledWithTwoIntegers_ReturnsTheirSum()
    {
        // Arrange
        var calculator = new Calculator();

        // Act
        var result = calculator.Add(2, 3);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(5, result);
    }

    private class Calculator
    {
        public int Add(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        new NUnitLite.AutoRun().Execute(["--noc" /*no colored output for .Net Fiddle*/]);
    }
}

XUnit Runner
Demo in JDoddle
The solution for XUnit was heavily inspired by this question on StackOverflow and this sample from the XUnit repo (more explanation can be found there).
I tried it on jdoodle and it worked without problems, but be a aware that I took some shortcuts compared to the sample code.

// configure the editor to reference the following packages:
// * XUnit
// * XUnit.Runner.Utility

using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using Xunit;
using Xunit.Runners;

public class CalculatorTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void Add_WhenCalledWithTwoIntegers_ReturnsTheirSum()
    {
        // Arrange
        var calculator = new Calculator();

        // Act
        var result = calculator.Add(2, 3);

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(5, result);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Nope()
    {
        Assert.Equal(5, 3);
    }

    private class Calculator
    {
        public int Add(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
}

internal static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var finished = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        using var runner = AssemblyRunner.WithoutAppDomain(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location);
        runner.OnExecutionComplete = info => OnExecutionComplete(info, finished);
        runner.OnTestFailed = OnTestFailed;
        runner.OnTestPassed = OnTestPassed;

        runner.Start();

        finished.WaitOne();
    }

    private static void OnTestPassed(TestPassedInfo info) => 
        Console.WriteLine("[PASS] {0}", info.TestDisplayName);

    static void OnTestFailed(TestFailedInfo info) => 
        Console.WriteLine("[FAIL] {0}\n{1}", info.TestDisplayName, info.ExceptionMessage);

    static void OnExecutionComplete(ExecutionCompleteInfo info, ManualResetEvent finished) => 
        finished.Set();
}

I hope this is what you were looking for!

Thanks cxanter - exactly what I was looking for
